# Should "Teachers" and "Students" be kept in a common "Person" table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I've already read these posts:

[Storing whether a user is a student or teacher? Is a lookup table necessary?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/189732/storing-whether-a-user-is-a-student-or-teacher-is-a-lookup-table-necessary)

[Creating a database for a scenario involving students, teachers and courses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238478/creating-a-database-for-a-scenario-involving-students-teachers-and-courses)

[In a school database, do I need to have repeating data when a student can also be a teacher?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156041/in-a-school-database-do-i-need-to-have-repeating-data-when-a-student-can-also-b)

All of them were close, but none are exactly what I want. A few points:

- This app will be used by Grade School teachers.
- A student will never be a teacher, and a teacher will never be a student.
- In addition to Students and Teachers, there will also be contact info for Admins who are neither students nor teachers.
- Teachers will always be Users. Admins may or may not be users. (We may store an Admin's name and contact info, but that admin may never have a reason or need to log into the app.)

My thought is to create a "Person" table:

- PersonId
- FirstName
- LastName
- Email (NULL if student)
- PersonType (Enum: 1 = Admin/Teacher, 2 = Student)
- Other Columns as needed

And another table "Passwords":

- PasswordId
- PersonId
- PasswordHash
- Other Columns as needed

If a Person is also a user, they will have a value for 'Email' and also a record in the Password table.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Consider how you'll query the database. Write the queries for different sections of your applicatoin. This should make it obvious if there is a single Person table or if Teachers/Students are distinct entities for your application. Its also unclear why a separate passwords table exist. Are you supporting multiple passwords per person?

Comment: I want to support password history. If a user changes their password, previous passwords should not be re-usable.

Comment: This would require exclusive subtypes, handled at length here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763141/data-modeling-supertype-subtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it depends (as most things go). What it'll mostly dependent on is how similar are your `Teachers` and `Students` objects. If they have a high similarity in attributes (very similar columns) then they likely can live in the same table. If they have more variation between the two objects, then likely you'll be better off [normalizing](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) the two entities into their own tables.

From your basic description of the application, my guess would be you'll find (if not upfront, over time) that the `Teachers` and `Students` entities vary enough that it makes sense to split them up into their own tables.

Further normalizing the attributes that they do share into a `Person` table is somewhat subjective, and for you to decide, but not a bad idea by any means for storing generic information like Email, Phone, and Address, etc.

The one thing I'd be careful with over-normalizing is the `Passwords` table, as that reduces natural obscurity that comes with it being denormalized and may slightly open your vector of attack up in your database design. (E.g. if someone unauthorized gained access to your database, having a table called `Passwords` automatically shows that person probably the most important table they'd want to compromise.)

Comment: Thanks, JD. Question then about storing password histories (so that a single password can't be re-used)... what is the best-practice way to do this?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston No problem! That's a good question, and maybe a little bit more focused for the [Security.StackExchange.com](http://www.Security.StackExchange.com). Unfortunately that's a little bit outside the scope of my expertise as a DBA, but from my limited knowledge I would say if you do need a Password history table, then using more obscure names like `AccountHistory` for the table may be a better choice. Additionally, storing only the last few password hashes helps reduce the amount of potentially sensitive data being stored at any given time.

Comment: [This article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4260/storing-passwords-in-sql-server--things-to-know-to-keep-the-data-secure/) may provide a little more guidance on best practices with designing a Password history table too.

Comment: Based on your answer, I just broke them out into separate tables :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the primary key should also include `PersonType`.

Then in each sub-table (`Teachers`, `Students` etc) you can create the same primary key which is also a foreign key on `Person`. This represents a 1 -> 0..1 relationship. The `PersonType` field in this table should be constrained to a single value